# how to figure out which statement in lapply fails in R

Tags: r, list, debugging, for-loop

I often have the situation like this:

```
result <- lapply(1:length(mylist), function(x){
doSomething(x)
})
```

However, if it fails, I have no idea which element in the list failed on doSomething().

So then I end up recoding it as a for loop:

```
for(i in 1: length(mylist)){
doSomething(mylist[[i]])
}
```

I can then see the last value of `i` and what happened. There must be a better way to do this right?? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running `traceback()`?

Comment: or use `print(x)` within your function (very slow)

Comment: @nrussell: traceback shows me the line of code that failed but it often doesn't show me the input in a readable format that went into that line of code.

Comment: @Floo0: print(x) really slows down the execution and prints a giant a mess -- although this would do in a pinch.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? I know you are looking for a general solution but it would help to be able to examine a specific instance and generalize from there.

Comment: @user1357015 why not use `print(x)` with `tryCatch`, e.g., `tryCatch(doSomething(x), error=function(e) {print(x);stop()})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how the error includes `5L`

```
> lapply(1:10, function(i) if (i == 5) stop("oops"))
Error in FUN(1:10[[5L]], ...) : oops
```

indicating that the 5th iteration failed.

Answer (score 2):

One simple option is to run the code:

```
options( error=recover )
```

before running `lapply` (see `?recover` for details).

Then when/if an error occurs you will instantly be put into the recover mode that will let you examine which function you are in, what arguments were passed to that function, etc. so you can see which step you are on and what the possible reason for the error is.

You can also use `try` or `tryCatch` as mentioned in the comments to either skip elements that produce an error or print out information on where they occur.